# jquery width() seems wrong in every browser I try except FF4

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accurately get the width of a `<td>` element. The results are what I expect in FF4 but in IE9/Safari 5 the result I get is 1 pixel off. It's been driving me crazy.

**UPDATE:**

My ultimate goal is to take the width from the cells in the ROWS table & apply it to the HEADER table's cells so each table's cells align perfectly. Doing this so it works for all browsers is my problem.

Here's a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/XwNEj/16/

Works in FF4 only :(
I'd greatly appreciate any help getting this work on all modern browsers.

Comment: Did you try to remove border-collapsing from there?

Comment: @user The issue is related to the cell border. If the cell has no border, then width() returns 200. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwNEj/12/

Comment: I'd really like to find a way to make this work regardless of borders being present or not.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed table headings see [this post](http://acatalept.com/common/test/fixed-table.html), or try [this](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html#) for a pure css solution.

Comment: That will give you value of "201px" in this case. But it should be `202 = 200px + 1px + 1px` (for borders), right?

Comment: In Chrome that gives you 201, rather than 200.  Depends on which way you want the discrepancy.

Comment: This wouldn't work for my purposes because the width value I get will be used to set the width on the header table's cells. Using outerWidth would cause the 2 not to line up.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? ** Sorry just saw your update

Comment: Please see my update as well. It gives a much better example of what I'm actually trying to do. The reason they are not in 1 table is because I need the header to remain fixed while the ROWS table will ultimately be in a div that allows it to scroll. I'm omitting such details though to focus on the specific problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: See updated answer. It seems you've run into a common problem of different widths of td's between browsers.

Comment: That's an interesting CSS example but fails in IE9 & I believe would suffer from the same width problem once you need to find the widths at runtime. The JS example also has the same width problem despite its hacks. The columns are not aligned in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's *wrong* precisely, it's more that table cells don't have the same box model as a div.  You can see this by playing around with the following:

- Use `.outerWidth()` and compare to `.width()`
- Add `display:block;` to your CSS for `th,td` and compare widths with the default table cell rendering.

I think you'll see what I mean.  This is also documented at  http://blog.anofsinger.com/2008/03/table-cell-box-model.html.

If you view the example http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/pqGhv here my intention is to show that the interior width of a table cell won't be the same as the interior width of a `div`, even if both are given `width:200px`.

However, while it might not be the width that you'd expect, and the width will potentially be different in each browser, the cells ought to be consistent *within* each browser.

(At least, that's what I'd expect.)  I'd expect this:

- You set a width of, say, 200 pixels to a table cell.
- Firefox might return a width of 199 and IE a width of 201.  Those widths are accurate and reflect each browser's table cell box model.
- If you set the same width to the `th`, it will render at the same width as the `td` as long as it has the same border and padding width.

But after looking at the example again today I saw that, either automatically setting the same width to each `th` as to its corresponding `td` with JavaScript or setting a generous equal width to both with CSS, the `th` sometimes ended up a different width from the `td` in the same browser.  (I have some sort of inarticulable thoughts about this, but suffice it to say it's really interesting when this discrepancy appears [and disappears]. I compared it setting a `width` vs a `min-width` vs giving `width:100%` to the whole table, etc.)

I take it your goal is a fixed table header.  For that, I do feel that it's much better to do as Mike showed and keep it all in one table using thead and tbody.  You break the "semantics" by using two different tables--the `th` no longer has any relationship with the `td`, except visually.

- However, you could use JavaScript something like this (it works in all my browsers at least and might be better than browser detection): http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/toCqs
- Using markup/CSS like this also fixed the problem for me http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/gjELD without JavaScript.  Uncertain if this works everywhere (I don't have IE9 for one) or if it can be used in the context you need.

Comment: So your idea is to replace `display:table-cell;` by `display:block;` ? For what purpose?

Comment: Goodness, no.  What would be the point of that?  It's not a solution, it's a demonstration of how the box model for table-cell is not the same as for block.  Therefore you can't expect to get the same result for .width() or .outerWidth() on a td as you would for a div -- and that result and how it varies will vary by browser.

Comment: Which leads me to realize I may have been unclear.  Does "it's most likely giving you the right width--the actual rendered space inside the cell, it's just that the number isn't one you expected to see." make it any better?

Comment: Perhaps it's not wrong per se, but it is inconsistent across various modern browsers. I want to take the width of the cells from the ROWS table and apply it to the cells in the HEAD table so the 2 tables align perfectly across all modern browsers. Haven't been successful yet :(

Comment: For now it's going to be inconsistent from browser to browser, because each browser uses a different model to calculate the width of table cells.  It should be consistent *within* the browser--but I guess that's the real issue, because I can see in that fiddle that the the th ends up a different width. I'll keep looking, but I think Mike's example is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems there may be no way to fix this other than to do a browser test:

Adding 1px to the width of non-mozilla browsers seems to work.
if(!$.browser.mozilla) { w++; }

I'm not crazy about the fix but haven't seen anything better yet. Hopefully browsers will agree on how to measure a table cell soon.

Even better why doesn't CSS support the concept of a fixed header table ?!?!

Comment: I'd go with something like this instead, rather than just adding 1px to a particular browser http://jsfiddle.net/gP2YG/11/